# itunes store operation failed in xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode6

`iTunes store operation failed`

`No eligible software found. Make sure this software is owned by your developer organization.`

I get above error while validating app from xcode 6. I don't understand this error why it is coming. Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Thank you

Answer (score 32):

I was able to upload by using Application Loader as suggested in iTunesConnect.

- Archive your app with the distribution provisioning profile
- Export the archive for distribution to somewhere you can find it again.
- Download Application Loader 3.0 from iTunesConnect, if it isn't already installed.
- Open Application Loader
- In AppLoader, Log into the iTunesConnect account you want to release the app from
- In AppLoader, Upload the archive

Not exactly painless, but it does allow you to build with an iTunes developer account and release from a different iTunesConnect ID.

Comment: As Matej Ukmar is saying in his answer, this is because you have a different account for your Dev Account and iTunes Connect. Using Application Loader enables you to log into iTunes Connect with the proper user.

Comment: He said what the reason was, which was helpful. I echoed that in the last line of my answer. The difference is that I also gave explicit directions instead of a 1-liner.

Comment: Same problem and the solution was exactly the one reported in this question. I did have two different developer accounts and was telling Xcode to use the proper one but when validating or submitting it was actually taking the other dev account ignoring my previous selection!

Comment: This is nuts. I have a developer account that is an admin on the team that owns the app. Everything works fine with code signing, but I can't upload the app, except by logging in to Application Loader using the iTunes Connect account I have as an internal beta tester with the Technical role.

Comment: This sucks. You used to be able to sign in to iTunes Connect with a different login within Xcode. Now you have to use Application Loader? Ghetto.

Answer (score 21):

I got this error while validating my app. The problem was that the developer account of which I was using the Provisioning Profile was different from that of the account that I was using to validate my app. In simple words: They were two different APPLE IDs.

You need to add the APPLE ID from which you are using the provisioning profile.

Follow the following steps to get rid of this error and add the APPLE ID:

1. After clicking on "Validate button" ---> Click on "View Accounts".

[image]

2. The following window will open. In this window click on + button as shown below.

[image]

3. A pop-over showing three option will be opened as shown below. Select "Add Apple ID".

[image]

4. A new window will be opened asking you to enter your Apple ID and password as shown below. Enter your Apple ID and password of the developer account from which you have used the provisioning profile. Then press "Add":

[image]

5. You will see a new Apple ID added in the list of the Apple IDs.
6. Close the Organizer window. ----> Archive the product again and Validate the app choosing the newly added Apple ID.

Comment: Having multiple Apple IDs in Xcode is very useful now and I'm pleasantly surprised that one can do it. Now I see the use case for it. The only semi-painful part is that you pretty much have to select the *other* account every time when you upload your app (for example, I use one ID as my "main development account" but I need the other Apple ID for uploading now). However, it's much better than being blocked entirely, being forced to use only one Apple ID at a time, or resorting to using Application Loader.

Comment: One caveat - it doesn't seem to work if you are just a member of the team of another account. You must use an actual account belonging to the organization which owns the app.

Answer (score 8):

This happened to me because I had a different developer and itunesconnect accounts. Make sure you build app with your developer account and submit validation with your itunesconnect account. That worked for me.

Comment: But this is absolutely ridiculous of Apple to force this. I develop apps for many clients and up to Xcode 6 I could distribute app & submit them via my Developer Account (s long as I was a member of their Developer Account). They are now saying I need separate Apple Developer accounts for every client I have.

Comment: You don't need to have a separate dev account for each client. Issue seem to occur if you have different your own dev and itc accounts. I think you can ask all clients to add your existing apple account to itunesconnect... then no issues

Comment: How do you add an existing apple account to iTC? If you mean via Invite user, then this invite cannot be for an existing email address (its says user already has an itv account). is this what you mean?

Comment: can you tell me how to add itunes connect account while creating .ipa from xcode 6?

Answer (score 6):

As noted by a few others, I was able to resolve this problem by using the Application Loader rather than xCode to send the iPA file to app store. In my case, both xCode and Application loader were using the correct iTunesConnect account, but for some reason, xCode was failing on submitting this app.  I could submit other apps without incident, which led me on a wild goose chase thinking the problem was app specific.

Steps to Resolution were:

1. Download to Application Loader from iTunesConnect Website (as of 2/18/15, it's under the Resources and Help button).
2. Install App Loader
3. From xCode, Build/Archive to create distribution package
4. From xCode Organizer, Export the package to a location
5. From App Loader, select the Exported Package IPA file and upload to App Store.

Glad to be past this one!

Answer (score 1):

For me it helped to upload with the credentials of the account **agent**. A developer account didn´t work.

Comment: even a developer with admin role didn't work as well. which was a surprise for me but when inspecting the role matrix it makes sense: https://developer.apple.com/programs/roles/

Answer (score 0):

in my application this issue was coming due to of one error that's i uploaded wrong size image in ipad2x that's **152*152** by **144*144** , but some how i export the build and i uploaded it through  application loader. application loader told me abt two warning after uploading the build that was not proper **icon  size image for ipad @2x** and the other was **64 bit warning** so i solved the icon problem and now i was abled to validate my app successfully with **one warning still that's of 32 bit**. if u had repeated the steps like you uploaded the build first from application builder than donot forgot to change build number.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the application bundleID from itunesconnect & your project in Xcode.We will get this issue if our bundleID mismatch from itunesconnect & project..

I was getting same error. After some investigation, I identify the issue with bundleID. I changed the bundleId as per itunesconnect. App was validated & submitted successful in App Store.