# xcode 6 upload app with error: iTunes Store operation failed Error Description not available

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect, xcode6

When I try to upload my app to iTC, after validate my app, I begin to submit it .
But there is an Error that said "**iTunes Store operation failed
Error Description not available**"
When I upload with Application Loader 3.0, same error happened.
[image: xcode6 error]
[image: Application Loader error]

Comment: The new "My Apps" section is not clear with the section that are required before you can deliver your app. The fact that the pricing section is separate but is required is just daft.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've got the Answer, 
just upload the ipa with **Application Loader 2.9.1**, even thought the apple tell  you that you should upload the ipa with xcode 5.1.1 or Application Load 3.0.0, but , my solution works well
[download Application Loader 2.9.1](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.9.1.dmg) or [here](http://pan.baidu.com/s/1qWCxTrI)

Comment: This is not a good answer, it's a workaround. Asif's answer below is correct.

Comment: Actually Asif's answer is valid in most cases. But I've experienced the same problem as in the question with the correct certificates, code signing, etc... The problem is that i've different accounts in Apple developer program and in iTunes connect. Since xCode 6 is using directly the dev account i'm not able to submit my app. Application Loader 3.0 has options to choose your iTunes account but it returns the same error. Currently the only solution is to submit wit Application Loader 2.9.1

Comment: The trick seems to be using indeed Application Loader, it's a bug of Xcode when you're using more than one developer account. See the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015808/itunes-store-operation-failed-in-xcode-6

Answer (score 29):

I had this error once, too. Then I realized the provisioning profile (Project Targets -> Code Signing) was set to 'Ad-Hoc' profile instead of 'Production' profile. Setting it back to 'Production' did the trick for me.

Comment: Even "Automatic" was not working for me. I had to select the distribution profile specifically to get it working.

Comment: The solution to this in my case is reported here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26015808/itunes-store-operation-failed-in-xcode-6

Answer (score 14):

The "**Error description not available**" sub-error message recently became "**You are not authorized to use this service**".

Removing the Apple ID from XCode preferences and re-adding it fixed the problem.

Comment: Even though this answer's a bit different from the original question, thanks so much for posting it (just a day before I happened to need it)! It was a big help. :)

Comment: After trying the other solutions, which did not work (I did not try the app loader) this also fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I used first the restricted account from me. I thought it would be asking for the agents credential but it didn't. Now I removed my account and added the agent one. Now it works!

Answer (score 6):

I'm a Chinese user and meet the same issue, I tried all these and fail:

1. Regenerate provisioning profile manually or via Xcode.
2. Use Application Loader (I didn't use 2.9.1 because I think it's a workaround).
3. Make sure your developer account are the same as iTunes Connect account.
4. Make sure bundle ID, version and build string in iTunes Connect and Xcode and the same.

Finally I googled and someone said it depends on network, so I opened VPN, and it success! I guess China's special firewall block something?

If you're in China and you've tried all the steps above, you can try to connect a VPN and upload your app. Wish it helps.

Comment: indeed the case in China mainland.

Comment: Yep, this was also my issue, but I was on an airplane during my first attempt, and on a hotel WIFI on my second attempt. Once I got onto a normal wifi network things worked great!

Answer (score 3):

As the error says, There is problem in uploading to iTunes Store and not in code signing. Code signing step is prior to uploading to iTunes Store. Once the ipa is created successfully it should be uploaded to iTunes Store.

I faced the problem and without changing anything It successfully uploaded after some time. I guess if we are doing some operation on iTunes Connect, in my case I was removing the build which was set for TestFlight beta testing. After I perform some changes there the issue occurred.

Not the definite solution.

Comment: I also faced this error. Exactly I faced this situation after I had submitted another app to Apple via XCode. So I just re-start XCode after minutes. And then I could successfully validate and submit my app (w/o no change).

Comment: I faced the same error while submitting the application from XCode 6. I just re-start XCode after some minutes and application validation and submission worked properly. (with no change).

Answer (score 1):

I had this error, and I found that it was because of the version number in my app. It had too many revision levels. You're allowed a maximum of 2. For example, 1.2.3 will pass validation, but 1.2.3.4 will generate the above error in Xcode 6.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in china use vpn. I fixed by use a vpn! The gfw block the upload api. you can check [this](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error and I tried for like 15-20 times but was out of luck. Then suddenly it stuck with me what if the network is causing this. Since I was on WiFi, I sat next to the router and it worked in the first go itself. Since there is no proper message by the Apple I tried even this and it worked.

**Note:** *If the size of the binary is quiet large then probably good internet connection is required too*.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks @prashant

Answer (score 0):

This is also workaround but you could upload app with Xcode 5.1.1, if you still have one. Generated with Xcode 6.1 *.xcarchive files are available from older Xcode so there is no need to generate *.ipa file.

Answer (score 0):

In [some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27365311/956397) it might be a notwork/firewall issue. Make sure your the [needed ports](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf) are open.

Also [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) must be working. Currently it is showing "iTunes Connect is unavailable until December 29"....

[Here](http://appadvice.com/appnn/2014/11/apple-to-disconnect-itunes-connect-for-the-holidays-from-dec-22-to-dec-29) is a blog post about it.
On week were no one will be able to update apps. Greate...

Answer (score 0):

**Just a tip:**
Before you start to change and installing things, try to:

- set the Provision profile to another one
- update your Provision profiles in your account
- close Xcode
- open Xcode
- set the Provision profile to the right one
- Archive again

it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

*In my case i user a wrong account with wrong password !*
*when i relogin, i fixed the problem, holp it will help you!*

Answer (score 0):

I have got this error when I tried to validate a build. 
It seems just a few minutes ago I could at least validate and got a different error (with version number, I  must increase it to 3.4.1 since 3.4.0 is already approved).

But it may be because I had a Pending Developer Release (v 3.4.0) . May be I have to release that version or cancel the binary. Otherwise I cannot validate the current archive.

I shall come back if that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

In my case what helped was... to wait. I had just deleted a version of the app and while itunes-connect appeared as I could upload another versione it takes some times to the servers to actually acknolegde this.
Waited until I got an email saying "App changed status to Ready for upload"

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me:

- Download the correct profile and certificate from member center;
- Quit XCode (Not just close the project);
- Try archive and validate again.

Answer (score 0):

I usually get over this with a simple workaround.I get this error when I try to upload archive from Xcode 7.So I archive my project with Xcode 7 but I handle upload process from Organizer of Xcode 6.3.Xcode keep organizer content same across different versions of Xcode.