# Archive submission failed in iTunesConnect

Tags: app-store-connect, submission

I am trying to submit my app to iTunesConnect from yesterday to now but, still not successful  on that.

When I am trying to submit the app over Xcode, on uploading archive step after a few seconds it says "iTunes Store Operation Failed" with "No Error description".

When I am trying to upload by Application Loader it says "Application Loader is currently unavailable, We are having trouble to connect App Store. Please try again later." again with "Error description not available".

I know yesterday iTunesConnect was in maintenance but I cannot figure out why I still cannot upload the archive yet. Is anybody else dealing with an error like that? Or have  an idea why this error happens?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your Code Signing set to Production Profile..?

Comment: Yes, it is set as Distribution profile.

Comment: Check these links:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202324/itunes-store-operation-failed-error-description-not-available , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051784/xcode-6-upload-app-with-error-itunes-store-operation-failed-error-description-n

Comment: Actually, I checked those all before asking this question. In my case, like 10 hours before I was starting to get this error, I submitted some other releases. Then, before 1 hour iTunes Connect was getting in maintenance I started to get this error. And it still continues.

Answer (score 0):

After renewing the distribution profile and some re-setting on code-signings, now, I am able to send archive to App Store.