# itunes store operation failed error description not available

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

First of all I know this question has been asked several times before, and I do try all the possible solutions. I have used Application loader 2.9.1 and 3.0 , I have used archiving from Xcode but it still the same problem. I have only one apple developer ID, so there shouldn't be any issue concerning that. I have tried to create a single view app from Xcode template and just add a distribution provisioning profile to see if there is anything wrong with my original app or not, but still I was not able to submit a simple template app to the iTunesConnect. 
I am getting really frustrated, any help guys would be really appreciated.

[image]

[image]

below are my info.plist and code signing part:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: first check network connection, and than check are you using latest apploader?

Comment: I am not using any proxy and network connection seems good. and yes I believe I'm using the latest one which is 3.0

Comment: SwiftBundleTest, Apple will surely reject app for ***Test***. I was facing this problem yesterday... when I upload today, its working... I would say restart MAC, XCode once... not sure what was problem...

Comment: I know it will reject that, that is just a test to see if I could submit a bundle.

Comment: That is really weird guys. Now That I am using VPN via my internet connection I can upload to the app store!!! I really don't know why is that. But now it's  working

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode 6 upload app with error: iTunes Store operation failed Error Description not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051784/xcode-6-upload-app-with-error-itunes-store-operation-failed-error-description-n)

Comment: I had this too once, the only thing that worked for me consistently was bumping the version number to something that I had never submitted before. Another thing I noticed was that sometimes uploading worked if I clicked on Validate... first (also in Xcode).

Answer (score 2):

Application loader require some TCP port to be open, you can check the requirement here, page 6, the doc is here : https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf . It is mention :

> For the best upload experience, verify that all of the ports and IP
>   addresses are accessible

And there is actually a lot of ports and ip !!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it says "We're having trouble connecting to the App Store.  Please try again later" in the application loader seems like a clue.

I am also experiencing the same problem today (same day as original poster). I suspect Apple has some problems at their end (i.e. the iTunes Connect server).

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same error. After reading the documentation of Application Loader, I just delete files on my mac to have at least 20 GB of free space, and guest what ? It worked! I can't believe it !

From the doc :

> Application Loader 3.0 requires a Mac, at least 512 MB RAM, and OS X
>   v10.8 or later installed. Apple recommends **at least 20 GB of available
>   space**