# iTunes Store Operation failed: Error description not available

Tags: xcode, swift, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm trying to submit a new build to iTunes Connect but I keep getting this error: iTunes Store Operation failed: Error description not available while submitting.

[image: Xcode error]

The strange thing is that I already succeeded uploading 3 builds to iTunes Connect. But now I keep getting this error, it has been happening for 4 days now so I guess it's not an issue on Apple's servers.
I tried changing build and version numbers, as wel as re-creating provisioning profiles etc.

Who can help? After 4 days this is kinda frustrating, I need to submit this app.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [xcode 6 upload app with error: iTunes Store operation failed Error Description not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051784/xcode-6-upload-app-with-error-itunes-store-operation-failed-error-description-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. The only thing I did different this time was the location where I did it. Turned out you cannot submit apps to Apple on some **networks**..

**Edit:**
You have to make sure that ports 443 and 33001 are avalaible.
More info in this document:
https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

Answer (score 1):

App submission requires some ports to be open, you can check the requirement document, page 6: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/UsingApplicationLoader.pdf

> For the best upload experience, verify that all of the ports and IP addresses are accessible

Xcode Organizer's requirements are the same with Application Loader.