# Getting error while uploading built to iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

I am getting error while uploading built. May be this error comes when internet is slow?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xcode 6 upload app with error: iTunes Store operation failed Error Description not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26051784/xcode-6-upload-app-with-error-itunes-store-operation-failed-error-description-n)

Comment: try to upload with Application Loader 3.0 and see activity. So, You can track where the error has occured.

Comment: Done with application loader, thanks bro...

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing upload build via one version later xcode or old application loader.